# How can I reuse a controller for multiple partial views?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to dynamically choose a partial view depending on what is sent to the controller, and have managed it but I feel that I am a) over complicating it and b) am unsure how to then easily get all page links. Each will be addressed in turn. Please ignore if I make a mistake below, it's from memory! At home it all works, I am after clarification on if there's a better way!

Firstly, what I've done:

I have a controller:

```
private Dictionary<int, string> pagesForFolder = new Dictionary<int, string>() {
         ... here I have my list of pages (index and pagename pairs)
}

public ActionResult Test(int id = -1)
{
   try {
        string pageName = "";
        var result = pagesForFolder.TryGetValue(id, out pageName);
        if(result) 
           string directiory = "~Views/folderA/_" + pageName +".cshtml";
           return PartialView(directory);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {  ... }
    return View();
}
```

Then in folderA I have all my partial views for that section of my website. I have many sections and 1 controller per section. However, I am thinking this won't scale out that great as I'll have to keep rebuilding every time I add a page. Would it be better to store the pages in the DB?

Comment: What do you mean "keep rebuilding every time I add a page" ? Do you mean part of the normal lifecycle of your app will be constant new views? Is it a customer / user specific thing? Or are you talking about "during development" time?

Comment: I mean won't everything have to restart if I change the controller each time (i.e. add another item to the dictionary) each time i make a new partial view or am i mistaken?

Comment: AS you have hard coded the list of pages. You have to re build your application whenever you add a new entry to yoiur dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your current approach is quite reasonable. I think your problem as you mentioned is you have to rebuild your application whenever you add or remove new entry to the dictionary.

As a solution for this you can store your page names in db and retrieve when you needed.

Instead of having a hard coded dictionary try something like this...

In your controller..

```
public ActionResult Test(int id = -1)
{
   try {
        string pageName =  GetYourPageFromDB(id);

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pageName)) 
                   string directiory = "~Views/folderA/_" + pageName +".cshtml";
           return PartialView(directory);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {  ... }
    return View();
}
```

This may not be the exact answer try something like this...

Comment: And adding a PartialView doesnt need a rebuild then? :) thanks

Comment: since your page names in the db you don't need to rebuild. But if you need to have new different server side logic in controller for that particular partial view you have to write the server side code and rebuild.

Comment: If these partial views contain some static data or the content is filled client side (ajax/javascript) by using predefined actions in the controller, you won't need to rebuilt the application..

Comment: In fairness, you can retrieve your pages dynamically from file storage as